# Adding a @Autowired to my Service Layer is making Junit Error Failed to load ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

Adding a @Autowired to my Service Layer is making Junit Error Failed to load ApplicationContext?

My firm has some comment code that we all core. I wanted to add it to my service today so I added it to the POM.XML and then I did:

```
@Autowired
private CoreDao coreDao;
```

Once I added this my JUnit Test started to give me errors.:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

so I commented the two lines out and everything works great.  why does adding the about two lines break my test

here is my jUnit Test so I dont know why its looking to it

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestDatabaseConfig.class)
public class TestApp {


    private static Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(TestApp.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private MemberInquiryService service;

    @Test
    public void testgetMemeberRequestInformation() {

        MemberRequest inMemberRequest = new MemberRequest();

        inMemberRequest.setRequestor("cpilling04@aol.com.dev");
        MemberInquiryInformation testInfo = service.getMemeberRequestInformation(inMemberRequest);

        Assert.assertEquals(testInfo.getFirst_Name(), "Christine");
        Assert.assertEquals(testInfo.getLast_Name(), "Pillings");
    }


    @Test
    public void testListMemberInquirys(){

        List<MemberInquiry> listMemberInquirys = service.listMemberInquirys();

        LOGGER.debug("Number of MemberInquiry(S) returned (" + listMemberInquirys.size() +")");


    }

}
```

I psted the stacktrace to https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KU-63IQBbptjVNGGImtEBL9VIk04CCGBFiJuIjp_8d0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show the logs before the failure?

Comment: Does your `TestDatabaseConfig` class contain a `CoreDao` bean definition?

Comment: Is there a full stack trace?  Do you have the same libraries avaiable in your JUnit as you do when you normally run?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis yes I did add the beans from CoreDao into the setPackagesToScan of my TestDatabaseConfig

Comment: I psted the stacktrace to https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KU-63IQBbptjVNGGImtEBL9VIk04CCGBFiJuIjp_8d0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can we see you CoreDao implementation?

Comment: It's pretty clear it can't find a CoreDao implementation to autowire.

Comment: but if I dont use JavaConfig and I use XML it works.  .. @Repository
public class CoreDaoImpl implements BeanFactoryAware, CoreDao {

Answer (score 0):

The is that the DataConfig was not doing a ComponentScan on the package with the core beans in it.

Example:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages= { "org.xxxx.inquiry", "org.xxxx.core" })
```

Answer (score 0):

two possibilities:

1. As SJS said, you forget the @ComponentScan and spring can't autowire you CoreDao to specific type.
2. If CoreDao is a JPA based, you need the corresponding table if you don't have the setup in persistence.xml:

I have the similar problem and I took few days to figure it out. Finally I put the value="create" instead of value="validate" to solve the problem.